# What is the SageMaker TensorFlow SavedModel export format?

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I'm new to AWS SageMaker TensorFlow 1.11.0 script mode. Been looking around the documentation for a while and can't seem to find the folder structure to export the model in after training. All I know is that I'm suppose to export to the directory specified in the env variable "SM_MODEL_DIR" and that the format is SavedModel.

I've used `tf.saved_model.simple_save` to export in the following folder structure:

```
- model.tar.gz
-- saved_model.pb
-- variables
--- variables.index
--- variables.data-00000-of-00001
```

But upon deploying, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/sagemaker/serve.py", line 189, in <module>
ServiceManager().start()
File "/sagemaker/serve.py", line 163, in start
self._create_tfs_config()
File "/sagemaker/serve.py", line 53, in _create_tfs_config
raise ValueError('no SavedModel bundles found!')
```

any help would be nice. Thx

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing this error because TensorFlow Serving (which SageMaker uses to host your model) requires the SavedModel to be nested in a version subdirectory.

Add a version directory your model archive to this structure to make it work. Example:

```
- model.tar.gz
-- 1
--- saved_model.pb
--- variables
---- variables.index
---- variables.data-00000-of-00001
```

See the [Load and serve a SavedModel in TensorFlow serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#load_and_serve_a_savedmodel_in_tensorflow_serving) section of the TensorFlow [Save and Restore Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) for more info.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Worked like a charm !! This was the only thing I was missing. `The version number inside the tar.gz file`.
They should be mentioning this clearly in the documentation too. Was a headache tbh!

Comment: @PrameshBajracharya I absolutely agree with you but Is there any way to update that model number dynamically because it will change every time.