# Adding a {serve} metagraph to existing Tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

The situation:

I've already created several models, trained over several days each, that we're ready to move from local testing to a serving environment.

The models were saved using the function

```py
def save_graph_to_file(sess, graph, graph_file_name):
    """Saves an graph to file, creating a valid quantized one if necessary."""
    output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, graph.as_graph_def(), [final_tensor_name])
    with gfile.FastGFile(graph_file_name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

Now when attempting to deploy to a serving environment (Sagemaker, using a correct directory structure and file naming convention), the system returns

```
2019-06-04 22:38:53.794056: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:54] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
2019-06-04 22:38:53.798096: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:259] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: fail. Took 83297 microseconds.
2019-06-04 22:38:53.798132: E tensorflow_serving/util/retrier.cc:37] Loading servable: {name: model version: 1} failed: Not found: Could not find meta graph def matching supplied tags: { serve }. To inspect available tag-sets in the SavedModel, please use the SavedModel CLI: `saved_model_cli`
```

All I have are the `*.pb` files and their label textfiles. These work lovely across multiple computers in local environments.

```py
def load_graph(model_file):
    """
    Code from v1.6.0 of Tensorflow's label_image.py example
    """
    graph = tf.Graph()
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with open(model_file, "rb") as f:
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    with graph.as_default():
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
    return graph

inputLayer = "Mul"
outputLayer = "final_result"
inputName = "import/" + inputLayer
outputName = "import/" + outputLayer
graph = load_graph(modelPath)
inputOperation = graph.get_operation_by_name(inputName)
outputOperation = graph.get_operation_by_name(outputName)
with tf.Session(graph= graph) as sess:
    # ... make a tensor t
    results = sess.run(outputOperation.outputs[0], {
        inputOperation.outputs[0]: t
    })
    # lovely functional results here
```

All I want to do is to take these existing files, add the "serve" tag needed, and re-save them, but everything I see seems to be related to doing this from scratch.

I tried to use the builder to append a graph to a model like so:

```py
# Load the graph
graph = load_graph(modelPath)
import shutil
if os.path.exists(exportDir):
    shutil.rmtree(exportDir)
# Add the serving metagraph tag
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(exportDir)
from tensorflow.saved_model import tag_constants
with tf.Session(graph= graph) as sess:
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess, [tag_constants.SERVING, tag_constants.GPU], strip_default_attrs= True)
builder.save()
print("Built a SavedModel")
```

but got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it. This contains some S3 specific code and S3 instance calls (the `!` commands) but you should pretty much be able to slice that out to run this.

```py
#!python3
"""
Assumes we've defined:

- A directory for our working files to live in, CONTAINER_DIR
- an arbitrary integer VERSION_INT
- We have established local and S3 paths for our model and their labels as variables, particularly `modelLabel` and `modelPath`
"""

# Create a versioned path for the models to live in
# See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54014480/1877527
exportDir = os.path.join(CONTAINER_DIR, VERSION_INT)
if os.path.exists(exportDir):
    shutil.rmtree(exportDir)
os.mkdir(exportDir)
import tensorflow as tf
def load_graph(model_file, returnElements= None):
    """
    Code from v1.6.0 of Tensorflow's label_image.py example
    """
    graph = tf.Graph()
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with open(model_file, "rb") as f:
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    returns = None
    with graph.as_default():
        returns = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, return_elements= returnElements)
    if returnElements is None:
        return graph
    return graph, returns

# Add the serving metagraph tag
# We need the inputLayerName; in Inception we're feeding the resized tensor
# corresponding to resized_input_tensor_name
# May be able to get away with auto-determining this if not using Inception,
# but for Inception this is the 11th layer
inputLayerName = "Mul:0"
# Load the graph
if inputLayerName is None:
    graph = load_graph(modelPath)
    inputTensor = None
else:
    graph, returns = load_graph(modelPath, returnElements= [inputLayerName])
    inputTensor = returns[0]
with tf.Session(graph= graph) as sess:
    # Read the layers
    try:
        from tensorflow.compat.v1.saved_model import simple_save
    except (ModuleNotFoundError, ImportError):
        from tensorflow.saved_model import simple_save
    with graph.as_default():
        layers = [n.name for n in graph.as_graph_def().node]
        outName = layers.pop() + ":0"
        if inputLayerName is None:
            inputLayerName = layers.pop(0) + ":0"
    print("Checking outlayer", outName)
    outLayer = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(outName)
    if inputTensor is None:
        print("Checking inlayer", inputLayerName)
        inputTensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(inputLayerName)
    inputs = {
        inputLayerName: inputTensor
    }
    outputs = {
        outName: outLayer
    }
    simple_save(sess, exportDir, inputs, outputs)
print("Built a SavedModel")
# Put the model label into the artifact dir
modelLabelDest = os.path.join(exportDir, "saved_model.txt")
!cp {modelLabel} {modelLabelDest}
# Prep for serving
import datetime as dt
modelArtifact = f"livemodel_{dt.datetime.now().timestamp()}.tar.gz"
# Copy the version directory here to package
!cp -R {exportDir} ./
# gziptar it
!tar -czvf {modelArtifact} {VERSION_INT}
# Shove it back to S3 for serving
!aws s3 cp {modelArtifact} {bucketPath}
shutil.rmtree(VERSION_INT) # Cleanup
shutil.rmtree(exportDir) # Cleanup
```

This model is then deployable as a Sagemaker endpoint (and any other Tensorflow serving environment)